# How to use PM2 to launch a nodeJS app as a particular user

Tags: node.js, pm2

I'm experimenting with a micro-service style node webapp.  Each user get's their own individual instance of the app.  I use some python scripts to fire up an individual instance of the user's node app when they log in.  After an amount of time without any user activity, the node app is shut down.

Each user has a linux user account on the system with their own home folder where they can store files.  To limit access, each app is run as under that user via the following command:

```
sudo -H -u user bash -c 'node-app -p 9000'
```

The problem doing it this way is that it's hard to monitor all the instances.  I was reading about PM2 for managing multiple node apps.  Is there a way to use PM2 to launch each instance as a different user?

Answer (score 1):

**Update**
Sorry these options were removed a while ago so this answer is wrong.

You can start your app with `pm2 start start.json` and set all options in start.json.

One of possible options is `run_as_user`

See docs here http://pm2.keymetrics.io/docs/usage/application-declaration/

Also there's a command line argument `--run-as-user`